# Broken 3.5mm jack input and sound quality very poor through usb soundcard

Tags: usb, sound, external-soundcard

The audio output 3.5mm is broken (physically cracked) and so you can still play music with it that sounds good quality but flicks between just coming out of 1 speaker to both speakers.

I bought a super cheap USB sound card and it works to play music but there is very little low end frequencies and the sound quality is generally poor.

Do you think it will be better if i invest in a better sound card?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon where you live and if you know where such work is done, and what kind of system you have, you might simply get the 3.5mm jack replaced.

You see, the 3.5 mm jack is straightforward, can be acquired from any decent electronics store and can be easily replaced.

If the system is a laptop, anyone with decent soldering skills can remove and replace the jack. That might be the best option for you (as you seemed to be happy with the sound from your older setup).